# Creating a 32 bit image and saving as tif

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, python-imaging-library, tiff

This is a very basic question but I do not seem to find a good solution to it. I want to create a black (all zeros) 32 bit image with dimension 244 X 244 and save it as tif. I tried some modules like PIL but all I got was a single channel RGB image. Any suggestions? Any links?
Thank you for the help and apologies if the question is too basic!

Comment: What do you mean by a *"single channel RGB image"*? Is it single channel or RGB image? It can't be both single channel and 3 channels of RGB data at the same time.

Comment: Please also show minimum, complete and verifiable code as required by StackOverflow - it makes it easier to test and help you. Thank you.

Comment: Also if you want an RGB image, it will likely not be 32-bit. It will likely be 24-bit, with 3 channels of 8-bits each. A 32-bit image would normally be RGBA, with 4 channels, i.e RGB + alpha.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hopefully this will help:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

# Numpy array containing 244x244 solid black image
solidBlackImage=np.zeros([244,244,3],dtype=np.uint8)

img=Image.fromarray(solidBlackImage,mode="RGB")
img.save("result.tif")
```

The image I get as a result can be examined as follows with **ImageMagick**, and seen to be a 24-bit image:

```
identify -verbose result.tif | more
```

**Output**

```
Image: result.tif
  Format: TIFF (Tagged Image File Format)
  Mime type: image/tiff
  Class: DirectClass
  Geometry: 244x244+0+0
  Units: PixelsPerInch
  Colorspace: sRGB
  Type: Bilevel
  Base type: TrueColor
  Endianess: LSB
  Depth: 8/1-bit
  Channel depth:
    Red: 1-bit
    Green: 1-bit
    Blue: 1-bit
    ...
    ...
```

Or, you can verify with `tiffinfo`:

```
tiffinfo result.tif
```

**Output**

```
TIFF Directory at offset 0x8 (8)
  Image Width: 244 Image Length: 244
  Bits/Sample: 8
  Compression Scheme: None
  Photometric Interpretation: RGB color
  Samples/Pixel: 3
  Rows/Strip: 244
  Planar Configuration: single image plane
```

---

Another option might be `pyvips` as follows, where I can specify LZW compression as well:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3
import numpy as np
import pyvips

width,height,bands=244,244,3

# Numpy array containing 244x244 solid black image
solidBlackImage=np.zeros([height,width,bands],dtype=np.uint8)

# Convert numpy to vips image and save with LZW compression
vi = pyvips.Image.new_from_memory(solidBlackImage.ravel(), width, height, bands,'uchar')
vi.write_to_file('result.tif',compression='lzw')
```

That  results in this:

```
tiffinfo result.tif
```

**Output**

```
TIFF Directory at offset 0x3ee (1006)
  Image Width: 244 Image Length: 244
  Resolution: 10, 10 pixels/cm
  Bits/Sample: 8
  Sample Format: unsigned integer
  Compression Scheme: LZW
  Photometric Interpretation: RGB color
  Orientation: row 0 top, col 0 lhs
  Samples/Pixel: 3
  Rows/Strip: 128
  Planar Configuration: single image plane
  Predictor: horizontal differencing 2 (0x2)
```